# How can i store an image with the same number but only duplicate name like "_01.jpg"

Tags: android

I'm storing an image with a number as its name. How can I store the image with the same number but only with "_01.jpg".

UPDATE: I'm taking a same picture twice. The first pic name's "123.jpg" and when I click same pic second time and save it, the name should "123_01.jpg". How can I do it?

```
String s3 = editText.getText().toString();
{ 
    Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), s3 + ".jpg");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f)); 
    imagaeToUploadUri = Uri.fromFile(f); 
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_PHOTO);
}
```

Comment: Why not `s3+"_01.jpg"` ?

Comment: Do you want the number to be increment for another img ?

Comment: can you please explain further...

Comment: Pradeep Deshmukh, No i don't want it to be incremented. All i'm doing is taking a same picture twice. first pic name's "123.jpg" and when i click same pic second time and save it, the name should "123_01.jpg"

Comment: Stanly Moses, All i'm doing is taking a same picture twice. first pic name's "123.jpg" and when i click same pic second time and save it, the name should "123_01.jpg" how can i do it????

Comment: Shree Krishna,
s3 is the i/p i'm getting from editText. So first time i need the pic to be saved with the same i/p number. only thing second when i save it, it should be "_01.jpg" (to my ref that it is duplicate of the first one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `exists` method to check if a given file already exists, and a `while` loop to increment a counter in order to find the next available filename.

Here is an example to get you started...

```
String s3 = editText.getText().toString();

File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String filename = s3 + ".jpg";

File f;
int c = 0;
while ((f = new File(dir, filename)).exists())   // f is assigned within the loop condition
{
    filename = s3 + "_" + c + ".jpg";
    c++;
}
```

Suppose `s3` is "somefile", this assigns `f` to `somefile.jpg`, `somefile_0.jpg`, `somefile_1.jpg`, etc, until an available filename is found (in other words until `f` doesn't exist). After the loop finishes, the file should be ready to use...

```
Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f)); 
imagaeToUploadUri = Uri.fromFile(f); 
startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_PHOTO);
```

Comment: @Moses Welcome to StackOverflow..!! make a habit of marking the answers as correct if they work for you. It is beneficial for you both. see : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235